# css library drawing a line and lock between html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I search a library (css/javascript) for drawing a line or better a line with a lock between two textbox. (could be other type than textbox)

[image]

[image]
I want to create whats inside the red rectangle.

Comment: it's just for aestethic or the lock should be clickable?

Comment: just aestethic (on change, one change the other value)

Comment: I think you need an image for this

Comment: with responsive page, the result will be weird. maybe if I only have lines.

Comment: I'm gonna try images. but I think it could be really interesting to have a css/javascript that could do it whatever the screen/text size.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses unicode symbols for lines and lock

```css
.locked {
   border: 0;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   gap: 1.75rem;
   width: max-content;
   position: relative;
   font-family: Arial;
}

.locked::after {
   position: absolute;
   left: calc(100% - .4rem);
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-55%);
   content: "\1F512";
}

.locked div {
   width: fit-content;
   position: relative;
}

.locked div::after {
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 1ch;
   left: calc(100% + .5rem);
}


.locked div:first-child::after { content: "\2510" }
.locked div:last-child::after { content: "\2518" }
```

```html
<fieldset class="locked">
   <div>
      <label for="tb1">Label 1</label>
      <input type="text" id="tb1" name="textbox1"/>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label for="tb2">Label 2</label>
      <input type="text" id="tb2" name="textbox2"/>
   </div>
</fieldset>
```